# Why is importing specific components resulting in the whole library in the bundle?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm following the recommendation to import individual components from react-bootstrap, like so `import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";`. I've verified the whole codebase and every single import is the same. Yet, when I analyze the bundle, it shows that react-bootstrap has been bundled in its entirety.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or a custom webpack config?  I’m not sure of the solution but it’s likely to do with webpack.

Comment: I used create-react-app, then to tree-shake, I followed this tutorial: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/tree-shaking-basics-for-react-applications where they described a specific webpack.config.js, I created the file under node_modules/webpack and pasted the config described in that tutorial. It seemed to work with Lodash quite fine, but not with react-bootstrap.

Comment: I struggle with tree-shaking myself.  But I would recommend removing your custom webpack config and seeing what happens.  Make sure that your react-scripts package and all of its dependencies are on the latest version.  I *think* that create-react-app now supports tree-shaking out of the box.  This stuff moves quickly and the article that you linked is over 2 years old, so it may not be the current best practice.

Comment: Right, that webpack.config.js was indeed useless as lodash is 'Tree-shaken' without it. This said, react-bootstrap is still not. Could this be because some other library I'm using depends on react-bootstrap and is importing the whole bundle somehow?

Comment: @LindaPaiste, so I dug a bit deeper and found that although react-scripts is installed in its latest version (4.0.3), in its package.json, I see it still references a specific version of webpack 4. How would you proceed to have it target webpack 5 instead?

Comment: Were you having the issue before adding the webpack config? The whole point of `create-react-app` is that it takes care of all of the compilation for you so that you don't have to configure babel, webpack, etc. The blog above is describing how to do it manually.

Comment: Yeah, I followed the steps in the blog to avoid having to import the whole react-bootstrap. I have created a clean app with create-react-app and I can see that webpack 4 is being installed by create-react-app and that react-bootstrap is imported in its entirety.

Comment: Any chance you are importing entire library instead of individual components?

Comment: @fxdxpz, no, every single import is done like this: `import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";`, which is the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I found that `react-bootstrap-dialog` was importing the whole of `react-bootstrap`. If you're here because of this same issue, I suggest you open `package-lock.json` and search for any libraries that depend on the unshakeable library, that's the one you should potentially replace.

<sub>Note: Answer provided by OP</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer given is correct, but it is not the only way. `package-lock.json` would be another file, I suggest you use the same one.
Hope I helped
Thank You :)